# Java : fatest way to restore a binary file of double values

Tags: java

I've a bunch of files (let's say 1'000, each between 1million to 10millions entries) full of double values in binary format (previously dumped by a DataOutputStream); what is the most efficient way to restore those double values in JAVA ?

Comment: The opposite of "Output" is ..? That is, what has been tried? Is it too slow? Where is the bottleneck, if anywhere?

Comment: Do not see the point "too slow/bottleneck" versus "fatest" way; if DataInputStream(BufferedIntputStream) is the fastest way then I'm fine with the response.

Comment: My point was 1) DataInputStream *is* the counterpart to DataOutputStream (Was it even tried?) and 2) *don't worry about "problems" that don't exist [yet]* (What is the bottleneck?). Hypothetical questions are just that: hypothetical .. (Although one easy way to kill file IO performance is to *not* use a buffered reader.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory mapped IO and [DoubleBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/DoubleBuffer.html)s?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the best speed I got is using a DoubleBuffer on top of a *direct* ByteBuffer; then whether using a MemoryMapped or a regular file is not yet very clear - MemoryMapped seems faster when cached by the OS (Win7).

Comment: I've just discovered that the actual buffer byte-order can be changed;  so if applicable, better to use "native-order" to avoid double values unmarshalling.

Answer (score -1):

Using DataInputStream:

```
  DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.bin")));
  while(dis.available() > 0) {
      double d = dis.readDouble();
      // ... do something with the double
  }
```

Comment: That is a misuse of available(). See the Javadoc. You should just loop until an `EOFException` is thrown.

Comment: Also, `available()` returns an integer, not a boolean .. there are entire dissertations on why using it can be problematic .. (In this case it *could* return 0, even on a stream that normally returns useful values, but still have data remaining in the stream to read before it is closed.)

Comment: Good point. Nevertheless, DataInputStream is the easiest way to go. You can easily also read the file length (file.length()) and read file.length() / 8 times of readDouble()

Comment: But why? Why not use the same code for all cases: files, sockets, URLs, ...?